# Issues in word file that generated by using html-dock-js-typescript

Tags: javascript, angular

I used

---

to generate html content into word file. But there ware unknown symbols and characters in generated word file.

**Html file -**

[image: entered text]

**Generated word file -**

[image]

**My sample code -**

```
const opt = {
            margin: {
                top: 100
            },
            orientation: 'portrait' as const
        };
        const doc = document.getElementById('my-doc');
        const contract = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);
        asBlob(contract, opt).then(data => {
            saveAs(data, 'my_word.docx');
        });
```

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/privateOmega/html-to-docx

Comment: Thank you @ShabbirDhangot. But same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully im not late to answer this question. You need to add
`<!DOCTYPE html> <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>` in your HTML output.